# Problems reading csv file in R

Tags: r, excel, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to read an csv file provided by an international bank (BIS). 
The data in question are a matrix of data for every half a year (so we have 2 matrix of data every year).
This csv file contains all these matrices for each year.

When I try to read it with R, I obtain a giant column vector with all the data in the rows. It seems to me that this file is a real mess.

This is the file [BIS](https://stats.bis.org/statx/srs/table/d6?p=20191&c=) in the top right you will find the download option

Can anyone with Rstudio give a try doing this? 
I don't know how to read this file properly.
Thank You

(1)  This is the image of the output of sessionInfo()
[image]

(2) This is the output of dput(head(x))

```
structure(list(Frequency..Derivatives.measure...Derivatives.instrument...Derivatives.risk.category...Derivatives.reporting.country...Derivatives.counterparty.sector...Derivatives.counterparty.country...Derivatives.underlying.risk.sector...Derivatives.currency.leg.1...Derivatives.currency.leg.2...Derivatives.maturity...Derivatives.rating...Derivatives.execution.method...Derivatives.basis...Period..30.06.1998.31.12.1998.30.06.1999.31.12.1999.30.06.2000.31.12.2000.30.06.2001.31.12.2001.30.06.2002.31.12.2002.30.06.2003.31.12.2003.30.06.2004.31.12.2004.30.06.2005.31.12.2005.30.06.2006.31.12.2006.30.06.2007.31.12.2007.30.06.2008.31.12.2008.30.06.2009.31.12.2009.30.06.2010.31.12.2010.30.06.2011.31.12.2011.30.06.2012.31.12.2012.30.06.2013.31.12.2013.30.06.2014.31.12.2014.30.06.2015.31.12.2015.30.06.2016.31.12.2016.30.06.2017.31.12.2017.30.06.2018.31.12.2018.30.06.2019 = c("H:Half-yearly,\"A:Outstanding - notional amounts\",\"A:Total (all instruments)\",\"B:Foreign exchange\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"A:Total (all counterparties)\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"A:Total (all sectors)\",\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\",\"USD:US dollar\",\"A:Total (all maturities)\",\"A:Total (all ratings)\",\"3:Total (all methods)\",\"C:Net - net\",H:A:A:B:5J:A:5J:A:TO1:USD:A:A:3:C,19168639.500,19152273.382,16570931.333,16504473.647,17872834.161,18034192.743,18340526.000,18976252.550,20062793.085,21044051.427,24842918.967,27753186.875,28401867.500,30250361.915,32530354.232,31530866.590,38308896.039,41071533.056,47782829.500,55333816.999,61778797.231,51013377.932,49245196.366,49565196.793,53615697.500,57490500.198,64325378.832,63517357.370,66711084.080,66852981.078,71298569.378,67974223.786,71903681.455,73329825.600,69380854.616,66121018.427,75421500.092,70549837.635,77043460.796,74755778.576,84448087.669,80187033.245,87298666.811", 
"H:Half-yearly,\"D:Outstanding - gross market values\",\"R:Options\",\"B:Foreign exchange\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"C:Other financial institutions\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"A:Total (all sectors)\",\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\",\"CAD:Canadian dollar\",\"A:Total (all maturities)\",\"A:Total (all ratings)\",\"3:Total (all methods)\",\"C:Net - net\",H:D:R:B:5J:C:5J:A:TO1:CAD:A:A:3:C,1161.745,1490.833,1222.830,926.167,736.515,886.684,521.715,489.581,707.685,717.633,2812.808,2584.250,1189.887,1944.300,1692.587,2290.471,1900.381,1832.126,2467.384,3870.651,2638.531,4853.416,2706.970,2641.239,3688.233,2450.827,2232.859,2583.502,2260.806,1978.314,2433.118,1952.467,1387.989,1986.367,2219.505,3074.150,2184.252,1583.677,1553.872,1006.964,1620.065,2488.795,2221.219", 
"H:Half-yearly,\"A:Outstanding - notional amounts\",\"I:Currency swaps\",\"B:Foreign exchange\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"A:Total (all counterparties)\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"A:Total (all sectors)\",\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\",\"JPY:Yen\",\"A:Total (all maturities)\",\"A:Total (all ratings)\",\"3:Total (all methods)\",\"C:Net - net\",H:A:I:B:5J:A:5J:A:TO1:JPY:A:A:3:C,665847.000,828299.777,875668.733,997412.428,1047157.268,1210319.093,1192194.500,1244771.126,1241944.495,1294832.734,1437403.185,1720086.950,1878897.500,2003401.146,1851924.243,2048809.372,2243689.109,2202208.431,2146344.500,2744258.005,3411821.256,3654503.689,3498381.192,3594992.084,3745016.000,4600142.746,5022018.814,5516718.531,5594858.545,5548180.113,5134517.612,4829745.267,5113758.357,4581584.271,4572681.667,4797919.225,5370243.655,4344600.559,4542005.956,4645791.421,4584187.724,4416611.460,4519339.546", 
"H:Half-yearly,\"A:Outstanding - notional amounts\",\"R:Options\",\"B:Foreign exchange\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"C:Other financial institutions\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"A:Total (all sectors)\",\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\",\"$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK\",\"A:Total (all maturities)\",\"A:Total (all ratings)\",\"3:Total (all methods)\",\"C:Net - net\",H:A:R:B:5J:C:5J:A:TO1:$TO1+TO1-USD-EUR-JPY-GBP-CHF-CAD-SEK:A:A:3:C,863774.000000,865406.583000,341270.120000,321820.219000,282976.779000,264876.921000,274639.000000,185779.556000,297179.339000,179406.909000,298459.222000,365627.174000,419059.000000,499553.253000,845687.310000,958955.986000,1385530.219000,1160054.774000,1482571.000000,1648450.768000,1640849.501000,1313883.398000,1693415.904000,1467928.225000,1651861.000000,1502669.157000,2189392.575000,1803339.324000,2142607.866000,2015002.239000,2555861.004000,2499453.527000,3487465.434000,3071346.036000,2719544.955000,2611233.989000,2947770.774000,2392687.361000,2691522.565000,2166422.213000,2880254.295000,2533027.458000,3259086.695000", 
"H:Half-yearly,\"D:Outstanding - gross market values\",\"I:Currency swaps\",\"B:Foreign exchange\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"U:Non-financial customers\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"A:Total (all sectors)\",\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\",\"JPY:Yen\",\"A:Total (all maturities)\",\"A:Total (all ratings)\",\"3:Total (all methods)\",\"C:Net - net\",H:D:I:B:5J:U:5J:A:TO1:JPY:A:A:3:C,30240.029,26367.119,21796.651,39716.323,32143.805,30389.383,26843.733,33348.754,26816.550,24846.505,28032.557,32684.944,28733.419,32619.585,23972.535,21118.101,22987.808,27127.087,31275.336,25613.000,30436.230,52996.239,44711.117,45134.484,61327.411,66779.399,56455.462,73471.624,56923.474,47455.524,37687.365,44021.966,34610.169,43803.691,38464.329,34709.350,35655.938,30928.526,25098.534,21729.101,20694.161,20778.855,21874.446", 
"H:Half-yearly,\"A:Outstanding - notional amounts\",\"D:Outright forwards and FX swaps\",\"B:Foreign exchange\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"C:Other financial institutions\",\"5J:All countries (total)\",\"A:Total (all sectors)\",\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\",\"EUR:Euro\",\"A:Total (all maturities)\",\"A:Total (all ratings)\",\"3:Total (all methods)\",\"C:Net - net\",H:A:D:B:5J:C:5J:A:TO1:EUR:A:A:3:C,...,...,1272146.000,1146532.000,1495971.000,1531690.000,1863753.000,1736941.463,1832240.044,2014960.537,2379459.961,2357957.575,2215394.000,2651638.060,2752256.120,2993819.901,3472744.796,3657614.085,4180902.000,5313264.061,6318377.654,5150962.524,4968054.122,4853194.748,4920499.000,5363941.450,6056293.101,5534031.443,5602769.833,5637073.889,5514261.347,5806103.816,6365877.653,6168319.645,6471464.934,5726248.815,6943219.557,6110293.984,7158136.521,7281429.632,7866597.943,7364160.600,7820522.046"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This file probably isn't in the right format to be read into R. My guess is the merged cells are causing an issue.

Comment: If you open the file in a text editor, you'll see that it isn't formatted properly, i.e. doesn't have the uniform number of delimited values per line that you would expect from a CSV file. You could try skipping the header lines

Comment: For some reason you have backslashes infront of the `"` (for example `"H:Half-yearly,\"A:Outstanding - notional amounts\"`).
When I open the csv file with a text editor these backslashes do not appear:
`"H:Half-yearly","A:Outstanding - notional amounts"`. Can you check whether you see the backslashes when you open the csv file with a text editor? 
And, do not open the csv with excel; if you have delete it and download it again.

Answer (score 4):

As @camille mentioned it, you have to skip some rows before reading data.

```r
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("table-d6.csv", skip = 6)
```

For me, it gives me a file with 527 rows and 58 columns (looks similar when I opened it with Excel)

PS: See @Cettt response for opening using read.table(). it works basically the same. The only difference I observed is that the function from `readr` seems to understand dates correctly:

```r
> tail(colnames(df))
[1] "31/12/2016" "30/06/2017" "31/12/2017" "30/06/2018" "31/12/2018"
[6] "30/06/2019"
```

Comment: I tried with readr like you said, but i still have a 521x1 column vector. I don't know why it's not considering the commas for separate

Comment: @Carlo, what command are you passing ? The function `read_csv` is using `comma` as separator, si there is no reason it is not working. Did you try to open the file in excel ?

Comment: I've added you the picture of what I see when I open the file in excel. Is your file different from the picture I posted? Thank You

Comment: I have the same file in excel. Do you use the command line that I provide you ? Did you try the one that @Cettt provides you ?

Comment: That's really weird ... can you give us the command you use ? and the output of the console if any ?

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use `read.table` with the following settings. Note that the file name is `table-d6.csv` and this file should be in your working directory.

```
x <- read.table("table-d6.csv", skip = 6, nrow = -1, sep = ",", dec = ".",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Some columns refer to dates. Since column names are not allowed to start with numbers, R puts an `X` in front of these column names. Therefore you have columns named like `X30.06.2018`.

Comment: I'm still obtaining a 521x1 column vector I don't know why. What can I do or check? Thank You.

Comment: Strange, please post the result of `sessionInfo() ` inside your question. Also post the output of `dput(head(x)) ` inside your question

Comment: I've just added the outputs